# XSLT 1.0: how to get print of first non-empty value of two (see inside)

Tags: xslt, attributes

I want to get first non-empty value of two and put it to "value" attribute of a text input. So, I do:

```
<input type="text">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="some/@attr != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="some/@attr" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="some/another/@attr" /> <!-- always non-empty, so get it -->
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

Question is: is there a way to make it with less lines of code?.. Maybe, like that: `<input type="text" value="some/@attr or some/another/@attr" />` or something?.. Like in, say, Perl: `my $val = 0 || 5;`

Thanks in advance for your help

UPD XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay magic is already in the answer form @Martin Honnen. 
As enhancement,to make it even a little shorter you can use "Attribute Value Templates"

```
<input type="text" value="{some/@attr[. != ''] | some/another/@attr}">
</input>
```

Comment: Martin have edited his answer and got rid of <xsl:if> constructions )) He supplied the idea, but your answer was exactly what I needed. Upvoted both. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 6):

If you use

```
<xsl:attribute name="value">
  <xsl:value-of select="some/@attr[. != ''] | some/another/@attr"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

then with XSLT 1.0 `value-of` semantics the string value of the first node selected by `some/@attr[. != ''] | some/another/@attr` is output. Thus if `some/@attr[. != '']` selects a node it should be output, otherwise `some/another/@attr` (as I think `some/@attr` is considered preceding `some/child-element/@attr` in document order).

Comment: Did an upvote, because the "tricky" part was from Martin Honnen.

Answer (score 3):

**Even the union can be avoided**:

```
<input type="text" 
       value="{some/@attr[string(.)]}{some[not(string(@attr))]/another/@attr}">
</input>
```

**Here we also avoid the precedence dependence of the two attributes** that is common to all other given answers -- we don't suppose that the first attribute precedes the second attribute in document order.

**We could write this equivalent code, reversing the order of the two AVTs**:

```
<input type="text" 
       value="{some[not(string(@attr))]/another/@attr}{some/@attr[string(.)]}">
</input>
```